# Proxmox OpenVZ /cluster/resources returning incomplete info

Tags: openvz, api, proxmox

I have a few Proxmox nodes, yesterday, I upgraded them all to 3.4-11. Today I found one of the node is not showing OpenVZ node correctly in the Proxmox UI. Then I did a bit investigation and found this missing information is from Proxmox API /cluster/resources. Then I tried to run pvesh get /cluster/resources from the node in problem, I got:

[image]

```
# pvesh get /cluster/resources
200 OK
[
{
"id" : "openvz/127",
"node" : "pve",
"type" : "openvz",
"vmid" : 127
},
{
"id" : "openvz/118",
"node" : "pve",
"type" : "openvz",
"vmid" : 118
},
{
"id" : "openvz/206",
"node" : "pve",
"type" : "openvz",
"vmid" : 206
},
...
]
```

Then I went to a normal node and run the same command, I got this:

```
# pvesh get /cluster/resources
200 OK
[
{
"cpu" : 0.000220895604811133,
"disk" : 774914048,
"diskread" : 0,
"diskwrite" : 0,
"id" : "openvz/124",
"maxcpu" : 1,
"maxdisk" : 5368709120,
"maxmem" : 268435456,
"mem" : 42786816,
"name" : "hostname1",
"netin" : 237953,
"netout" : 153381,
"node" : "fr000",
"status" : "running",
"template" : 0,
"type" : "openvz",
"uptime" : 3809,
"vmid" : 124
},
{
"cpu" : 0.000220895608544508,
"disk" : 2063126528,
"diskread" : 0,
"diskwrite" : 0,
"id" : "openvz/122",
"maxcpu" : 2,
"maxdisk" : 42949672960,
"maxmem" : 2147483648,
"mem" : 634228736,
"name" : "hostname2",
"netin" : 34106,
"netout" : 33882,
"node" : "fr000",
"status" : "running",
"template" : 0,
"type" : "openvz",
"uptime" : 3827,
"vmid" : 122
},
...
]
```

So apparently the node in question does not return enough information about OpenVZ containers.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by removing an underscore from the value of HOSTNAME from /etc/pve/nodes/pve/openvz/130.conf.